# Rails i18n how to get all values for a certain key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, key, key-value, rails-i18n

In Rails i18n, how to get all values for a certain key using the following:

```
translations = I18n.backend.send(:translations)
```

**get all the keys**

I need to be able to get a *certain section* for example only return everything under "home"

```
en:
  home:
    test: test
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The return value of `I18n.backend.send(:translations)` is just a hash, so you can access a subset just by passing in the appropriate keys.

e.g. if you have:

```
en:
  foo:
    bar:
      some_term: "a translation"
      some_other_term: "another translation"
```

Then you can get the the subset of the hash under `bar` with:

```
I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:en][:foo][:bar]
#=> { :some_term=>"a translation", :some_other_term => "another translation"}
```

Comment: Thanks i found out in the meantime that I18n.t('home') works also

Comment: Nice, thanks! this worked great for me as I was looking for a way to get the actual key name.

Answer (score 5):

The default I18n backend is `I18n::Backend::Simple`, which does not expose the translations to you. (`I18n.backend.translations` is a protected method.)

This isn't generally a good idea, but if you really need this info and can't parse the file, you can extend the backend class.

```
class I18n::Backend::Simple
  def translations_store
    translations
  end
end
```

You can then call `I18n.backend.translations_store` to get the parsed translations. You probably shouldn't rely on this as a long term strategy, but it gets you the information you need right now.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `I18n.locale` then doing `I18n.t` works fine, e.g.:

```
def self.all_t(string)
  I18n.locale = :en
  en = I18n.t("pages.home.#{string}")
  I18n.locale = :fr
  fr = I18n.("pages.home.#{string}")
  [en, fr]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but I just had to extract all the country codes from a Rails locale file, and the suggestions above did not work for Rails 6 and i18n 1.12.

Turns out that the `translations` method on `I18n::Backend::Simple` is now public, so we can now use :
`I18n.backend.translations(do_init: true)` to retrieve the translations hash.

Therefore the `home` node mentioned above can be retrieved with :
`I18n.backend.translations(do_init: true)[:fr][:home]`

Hope this helps